# How to get the result from request body

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, httpwebrequest

I use Node js

Using cheerio library, I try to parse a page.

By request, I got body of a webpage.

In this body, I want to get contents of

Below is my code :

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');

 request('http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Ffortune.daum.net%2Fexternal%2F4%2Frun%2Fstar_free%2Findex.php%22%20and%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20xpath%3D%27%2F%2Ftd%5Bcontains(%40style%2C%22font-family%3A%EA%B5%B4%EB%A6%BC%3B%20font-size%3A12px%3B%20color%3A%23333333%3B%20line-height%3A18px%3B%20padding-right%3A10px%22)%5D%27&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys',
function(error,response,body){ 

console.log(body);
//var info =JSON.parse(body);
});
```

The result of 'console.log(body)' is 'XML'. And I want to get contents of

And Can I convert it to JSON??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Yahoo's documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/response.html), you just need to add the `format=json` query string parameter.

Comment: Thank you but What I received is like this : "{\"query\":{\"count\":4,\"created\":\"2014-11-07T15:10:16Z\",\"lang\":\"en-US\",~ Not general JSON TYPE ... IS THERE SOMETHING I miss? ANY WAY THANK YOU!

Comment: That *is* JSON, what else are you expecting?

Comment: I'm newbie Sorry. But actually what I got generally is like {"query" : { "count":"4", "created" : "2014" ~ Not "{\"query\":{\"count\"~} because of this difference, I got JSONException I think...

Comment: My purpose is to extract some string values from that json string. sorry to disturb you

Comment: You have to parse JSON, just like you have commented out in your code.